# Pulling cards from other decks and adding them to another deck

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014

Some decks have some incredible cards that I would like to add to my elf deck. Is it possible to either remove some cards from other decks and add them to your own or perhaps buy specific cards online and add them to your own?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately not.

While Duels of the Planeswalkers adds more features with each edition, it still doesn't have a proper deck building feature and probably never will. It's a game based on MtG and designed to attract new players but Wizards still want players to move to MtGO or paper Magic.